# Recreate IWebElement

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to recreate web elements as i have a listener attached to the webdriver, if I pass an element to a javascript method it fails with a system reflection error.

What I need is something like this

```
public static IWebElement NewElement(IWebElement element)
{
    IWebElement newEle = element;
    return newEle;
}
```

but clearly this doesn't work. Anyone got any workarounds or solutions?

Comment: Why you need to clone an IWebElement? Maybe this is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

To recreate the elements you are looking for the Page Object Model approach. For more information on this approach:

[Seleniums Suggestions](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp)

[Videos on POM with C# and Java](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCO1aucBAJgFR8odzfXOZ5uw/featured)